# .htaccess redirect directory 1 to directory 2 without matching directory 2

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a situation where I'm trying to redirect all visits to site.com/news to site.com/dir/news. No matter what I do, I can't seem to match the site.com/news without also matching site.com/dir/news which results in an infinite redirect loop until the browser times out.

Here's my current code. Does anyone see what I'm missing here?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)news $1dir/news [R=301,L]
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^news(.*) dir/news$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm. Thank you so much! I don't understand how that worked, so to make things easier in the future, could you explain the key difference in your code that made it work?

Comment: Glad to hear it works. The difference is that your regex was capturing any request that had the word `news` in it whereas mine captures only those that begin with `news` (the `^` sign denotes the beginning of a string). Secondly, you were placing whatever occurred before `news` to before `dir/news` whereas I'm placing it after (the `$1`).